# Use 3 email providers for the same domain

Tags: email

I am using 3 providers for my domain:

Zoho handle incoming emails
SparkPost handles sending transactional emails
Amazon SES handles sending marketing emails.

Now, i've added all their entried to my domain records.
Will I have problems with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be ok.

These days it is rare for mail flow to be symmetrical inbound to outbound. There are often extra hops inbound (for spam and virus scanning) and various sending sources for outbound (based on geo-location, etc.). As long as your MX and SPF (and of course corresponding A and PTR) records are correct to clearly define your paths and allow external sources to find your servers for sending you mail, and verify your sending servers are legit, there should be no issue.

Naturally if your outbound emails are seen as spam that causes other issues... but it is not an architecture/configuration issue at that point.